# CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent と CGEventPost の組み合わせで CGPostKeyboardEvent でできたことを実現したい

Tags: macos, objective-c, quartz

OSXプログラミングをしていて、Control-F4 といったキーボードショートカットのキーシーケンスをアプリで生成したいのですが、`CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` と `CGEventPost` を使ってもうまくいきません。`CGPostKeyboardEvent` を使って同様のキーストロークを発生した場合にはうまく動きました。しかしながら、`CGPostKeyboardEvent` は deprecated になってしまったので、別の方法をさがしています。

```
CGPostKeyboardEvent((CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)118/*F4*/, true); // worked

CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)118/*F4*/, true)); // doesn't work
```

どのようにすれば、`CGPostKeyboardEvent` のようにキーボードショートカットのアプリでの実行ができるようになるかお教えいただけると幸いです。こういった、システムにかかわるキーボードショートカットを発行できてしまうことが、`CGPostKeyboardEvent` が deprecated になってしまった理由ではないかと思わなくもないのですが…

Answer (score 4):

たとえば以下のようにすれば良いと思います。

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

        CGEventRef f4 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, kVK_F4, true);
        CGEventSetFlags(f4, kCGEventFlagMaskControl);
        CGEventTapLocation location = kCGHIDEventTap;

        CGEventPost(location, f4);

        CFRelease(f4);
        CFRelease(source);
    }
    return 0;
}
```